# Show all product review on product page

Tags: magento2, product-review

[image]

Is there anyways that I can display all reviews of products if I don't want to use pagination anymore?

Comment: yes, you can do that by customization, but remember it will affected page length where more reviews on product.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya how could I do that?